# Hive jdbc driver respond with non descriptive message

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I prepared java application that calls Hadoop DB using hive jdbc client.
When I trying do simple queries like 'select * from students' it's works fine.
But as soon as I adding some conditional statements (for example, where age > 10 ) it starts respond with exception as following:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 2, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:194)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:441)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
    ... 29 more
```

Only possible reason that I found in google it's missing library. But for me it's look weird that I need additional lib for more complicated query.

Just in case here is dependencies list from build.gradle

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-core:"+spring_version
compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:"+spring_version
compile "org.springframework:spring-context:"+spring_version
compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:"+spring_version

compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.1"

compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.0.0'

compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:0.13.0'
compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-exec:0.13.0'
compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-service:0.13.0'
compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:0.13.0'

compile 'org.apache.thrift:libfb303:0.9.2'
compile 'org.apache.thrift:libthrift:0.9.2'

compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.15'
compile 'org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5'
compile 'org.apache.derby:derby:10.10.1.1'
compile 'javax.jdo:jdo2-api:2.3-eb'
compile 'jpox:jpox:1.1.9'
compile 'jpox:jpox:1.1.9'
```

and spring config for jdbc template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:spring/application.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />

    <!-- basic Hive driver bean -->
    <bean id="hive-driver" class="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" />

    <bean id="hiveSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource"
          c:driver-ref="hive-driver" c:url="${hadoop.jdbc.driver.path}"
          c:username="${hadoop.login}" c:password="${hadoop.password}" />

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
          c:data-source-ref="hiveSource" />

    <bean id="hiveDao" class="com.sample.dao.HiveDao">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="hiveClient" class=" com.sample.client.HiveClient">
        <property name="hiveDao" ref="hiveDao" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Please advise or share with working example.

Best Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use,
    `<bean id="hive-driver" class="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"` /> instead of `<bean id="hive-driver" class="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" />`